# Wicket FeedbackPanel not showing

Tags: wicket, feedbackpanel

I have a few pages with a form. Every form has a `AjaxButton` for submitting and a

```html
<div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
```

for the feedback panel. Every form field is required and the `FeedbackPanel` gets correctly filled with error messages from validators in case you leave one field out. The problem is those messages are displayed only if I hit "back" on the browser and then "forward" to see the page again, no matter where I place the feedback `<div>` inside the page.

Until the back/forward gesture, no error message appear, but the form does not reach `onSubmit()` (obviously, there are validation errors).

The problem is common to all of my pages that have a form and a `FeedBackPanel`. All pages make use of *Bootstrap 3.2.0*, just in case that could make any difference.

Any clue about what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you using Ajax, you have to add components, which you want to be updated into `AjaxRequestTarget`.
Components, which will be updated by Ajax must have predefined markup id.

So, you have to call `setOutputMarkupId(true)` method for your `FeedbackPanel` and override `onError` method for `AjaxButton` :

```java
... = new AjaxButton (...) {

         ...

         @Override
         protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form form) {
             /*here add your feedback panel to be updated via ajax*/
             target.addComponent(feedbackPanel);
         }
     }
```